# Как правильно сделать inflate <include> - элементов

Tags: java, android, android-xml

В коде активити у меня есть следующий код:

```
<!--ITEMS-->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout_rating"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_facebook_invite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey">

<include android:id="@+id/firstItem" layout="@layout/invite_item"/>
<include android:id="@+id/secondItem" layout="@layout/invite_item"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

И сам элемент include которого  я делаю:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_height"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Партнерство"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:textSize="@dimen/item_title_text_font_size"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="Сооснователи, создание компаний"
        android:textColor="#535353"
        android:textSize="@dimen/item_description_text_font_size"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Как мне правильно делать inflate одного и того же элемента? И вообще можно ли так делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то так

```
 View firstItem = findViewById(R.id.firstItem);
 TextView title = firstItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
```